# Acer Aspire V3-571g fan does not start once stopped

Tags: drivers, 18.04, overheating, fan

my laptops fans behave very strange on Ubuntu.
My laptop is a Acer aspire V3-571g.

I will try to explain what happens.

When i first boot my laptop every thing works fine.
Then after a while it starts to overheat since the fan does not start.
This force me to shut down my computer and when start it again a few seconds later a strange thing happens:
If i stay in bios mode until the bios starts cooling, my fans work.
Then i can continue and boot Ubuntu and every thing works fine.

So my Question:
Is it possible that my fans need a high initial voltage to start?
How can i force my laptop to start cooling in the first place?

Thanks for your help and time,
Thomas